# Setting Commit and Checkout Privileges for a Git Repository

Tags: linux, git, permissions, file-permissions

We are having a local repository which is accessible to a large number of people. We have to set up a Git repository there such that only certain users have checkout as well as commit privileges. How can we do that.

P.S. : This is a part of our homework assignment in which we have to develop a game and update it using a Git repository. So, if anyone feels like we should not be asking this question here, please do tell.

Comment: Questions regarding your homework are always welcome, but don't expect others to solve your homework for you.

Comment: YEAH.. it is a very small part of the problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend [gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) to manage user access to the repository.

#### Edit after comments:

`gitolite` is installed via `git` too.

I'm guessing that your teacher probably also meant to teach you – besides using git – to configure git protocols, ssh access (keys etc.).

You already got best advices: `gitolite`, `gitosis`, `Pro git`, adding to this `man ssh`, `man ssh-keygen`, `man scp` and git manual your homework should be easily solved.

Comment: Or **gitosis** (see also relevant chapter in free "Pro Git" ebook).

Comment: we cannot install any new software for the task unless absolutely necessary because we don't have the root access to the machine.

Comment: we need to set up a local repository.. :-(

Comment: gitolite does not require any root access to a machine. ssh access is sufficient. Please read the documentation.

Comment: @djs: Perhaps the point of the the homework is to learn how to use Unix permissions (owner, group-owner, other; read, write, execute). An SSH-based tool like gitolite or gitosis would work against this purpose (though it would be *another* good homework problem).

Comment: thanks all. I solved the problem using SVN. The homework is about making a game which should be maintained on a local GIT Repository. (SVN was added later due to some issued).thanks takeshin.. for the invaluable information.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is homework I will try to give hints.

- What files and directories do other users need to read to access (or write to commit/push into) a repository?
- What methods can you use to control the permission on these files and directories?
- Does your application have any configuration options that might help?